# Is it allowed to refer to Artificial Neural Networks as Statistical learning?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, terminology, academia

I am producing a research statement to be sent to a statistics department and I was trying to avoid the term Machine learning in favour of the more friendly one of Statistical learning. Probably I could not avoid such use.

Comment: Yes, it's completely reasonable to call ANNs statistical learning. You may enjoy Leo Breiman's discussion paper [Statistical Modeling: The Two Cultures](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/statistical-science/volume-16/issue-3/Statistical-Modeling--The-Two-Cultures-with-comments-and-a/10.1214/ss/1009213726.full).

Comment: people in stats departments usually know what neural networks are, if they are not interested in that topic, they won't be interested in it even if you call stat. learning if they are interested in that topic, they will also be interested in it if you call it machine learning.

Comment: What about "statistical inference"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The classic [The Elements of
Statistical Learning](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/ElemStatLearn/) handbook by Hastie et al discusses neural networks among other algorithms, so it needs to be a “statistical learning” algorithm.

Depending whom you’d ask, neural networks are either statistics, statistical learning, pattern recognition, machine learning, deep learning, or artificial intelligence. There’s no single, agreed category used by everybody to describe them.

Comment: I think the answer is implied in this statement, but it isn't quite explicit. It may be worth adding another sentence ;-).

Comment: I know the textbook and that was one of the reasons suggesting me to do so. Yet others disagree.

Comment: @MrFrog it’s either statistics, statistical learning, pattern recognition, machine learning, deep learning, or artificial intelligence. Each one of those has it’s fans and enemies. There’s no single term that everybody uses.

Answer (score 5):

That's a political question, not a statistical one :-)

Historically, statistics and machine learning were two distinct communities, with little interaction. ANNs were developed by the machine learning community. Today, the lines might be somewhat blurred, with some statisticians counting ANNs to statistics, while some machine learners count logistic regression and even linear regression to machine learning. Needless to say, some members of the opposite camp beg to differ.

So, there is no simple answer to your question. Calling ANNs statistical method might be seen as justified by some and objected to by others.